# Getting twitter oAuth user and secret key

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I have made a php script for tweeting via API. Right now I added an app(say "MyTweets") in my twitter account and got secret and oAuth key. Now I want others to use it. Right now I have put hard coded Key and secret, how can I automate it so that use can 'Add' their twitter account in my application or atleast I can store their oAuth/Secret for automated use. I just don't want to add new apps every other twitter account.

Answer (score 3):

go to the link below: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Fill up the form then submit.

now you will get your oAuth user and Secret Key

Comment: i am able to find key and secret,point is, how others will use my app?right now I have hard-coded oauth key and secret, how others can use my website? how to get their key and secret?

Answer (score 0):

See the API docs at [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth).  You're going to need to implement OAuth in your application so that the user can authenticate with Twitter and you get back the authentication token you use in your application.